# In R: How to tell R that a value should be inserted into a categorical column while applying two conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements

What we have:

```
companyID   year   status
    1       2010     
    1       2011     
    1       2012     2
    1       2013     
    1       2014     
    2       2007     
    2       2008     
    2       2009     2
    2       2010     
    2       2011     
    2       2012     1
    2       2013
```

For companyID 1: I have the observation with status 2 in year 2012. I would want R to make any observations prior to that as status 1 (by companyID). Then I would want R to make observations after that (the status 2 in 2012) to a status of 2 (still per company).

For companyID 2: I have the observation with status 2 in year 2009. i would want R to make any observations prior to that as status 1 (by companyID). Then I would want R to make observations to status 2 until a status 1 shows up again (still per company).

(Summing up: Fill in the other value (1) before the one that is already there (2), then continue with 2 until there is another change (change as in: either that there is a new company or that there was a status change that had already been stated in the original dataframe))

This would then look like the following, and is what we want to acheive:

```
companyID   year   status
    1       2010     1
    1       2011     1
    1       2012     2
    1       2013     2
    1       2014     2
    2       2007     1
    2       2008     1
    2       2009     2
    2       2010     2
    2       2011     2
    2       2012     1
    2       2013     1
```

We have a large dataset and that is why this would not be possible manually. Is there a way to code for both of the companyID’s simultaneously (and hence for all the thousands of observations we have) in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(companyID) %>%
  fill(status) %>%
  mutate(status = replace(status, is.na(status), 
                         ifelse(na.omit(status)[1] == 1, 2, 1))) %>%
  ungroup

#   companyID  year status
#       <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1         1  2010      1
# 2         1  2011      1
# 3         1  2012      2
# 4         1  2013      2
# 5         1  2014      2
# 6         2  2007      1
# 7         2  2008      1
# 8         2  2009      2
# 9         2  2010      2
#10         2  2011      2
#11         2  2012      1
#12         2  2013      1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(companyID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L), status = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked great :)